# Piping to executable with extra params

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, pipe, xargs

I have such a command using pipe

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python
```

on the other side I want to provide extra arguments to `get-poetry.py` script as below

```
python get-poetry.py --version 0.7.0
```

How do I pipe that properly and whether it's possible at all?

Currently I'm trying to play around with `xargs` but no luck with commands like this

```
curl -sSL get-poetry.py | xargs -I {} python "{}" --version 0.7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems like this works as required

```
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python /dev/stdin --version 0.7.0
```

Anyway, in case you have some other proper working solution I'd like to see those approaches as well